# convert a list of dicts to a dict of dicts python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, for-loop

I have a list of dicts which looks like this

```
a = [{'name': 'analyst21', 'id': 1, 'data': 'the process data3'}, {'name': 'analyst2', 'id': 2, 'data': 'process data2'}, {'name': 'analyst3', 'id': 3, 'data': 'process data3'}]
```

i want to convert it to dict of dicts

Required output:

```
a = {{'name': 'analyst21', 'id': 1, 'data': 'the process data3'}, {'name': 'analyst2', 'id': 2, 'data': 'process data2'}, {'name': 'analyst3', 'id': 3, 'data': 'process data3'}}
```

I Know that dict needs key-value pairs. Is any other way to make it possible. is my question is wrong. Got some negative votes.  I just want the list data to be enclosed inside this {} . I use these results for further processing.

Comment: The literal in your second code block is not a dict, though. `{a:b, c:d}` is a dict. `{e,f,g,h}` is a set. Do you want a dict or a set? If you're still sure you want a dict, what should the keys be?

Comment: Dicts have keys.  The outer structure in your output does not have keys and so is not a dict.

Comment: You cannot have a dict of dict because dicts are mutable and cannot be used as dict keys

Comment: Yes i know. i need a key value pair. but, is there any other way to make it possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python dict [is key-value structure](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#mapping-types-dict). Your required output is not a dict - dict **must** have both keys and corresponding values (or be empty). If you want to convert a list of dicts to a dict of dicts, you should chose a some kind of hashable key (note that dict itself is not hashable so you can't use ordinary dicts as keys!) and use them as dict keys. Here is the example how you can to do it:

```
a = [{'name': 'analyst21', 'id': 1, 'data': 'the process data3'},
     {'name': 'analyst2', 'id': 2, 'data': 'process data2'},
     {'name': 'analyst3', 'id': 3, 'data': 'process data3'}]

b = {d['name']: d for d in a}
b
```

will return you a dict:

```
{'analyst2': {'data': 'process data2', 'id': 2, 'name': 'analyst2'},
 'analyst21': {'data': 'the process data3', 'id': 1, 'name': 'analyst21'},
 'analyst3': {'data': 'process data3', 'id': 3, 'name': 'analyst3'}}
```